# Match last URL param including slashes in Koa router

Tags: koa, koa-router

I use `koa-router`, and would like to match part of the URL (potentially) including slashes.  For instance, everything that matches `/foo/xxx`, `/foo/yyy`, `/foo/dir/xxx`, and `/foo/a/b/c/d`.

Something like the following, if `*path` meant the same as "`:path` but including slashes":

```js
router.get('/foo/*path', async (ctx) => {
    console.log(`PATH: ${ctx.params.path}`);
});
```

Being able to say "catch everything starting with `/foo/`" would work as well.

I am stuck here, I don't find any way for `koa-router` to allow me to do this.

Comment: Can you tell me which version of koa router you are using by looking at your `package.json` file? I have been using `@koa/router` and can simply do `router.get('/foo/:splat*', async (ctx) => {});` to achieve what you might be looking for.

Comment: @RubekJoshi Yes, that's it, thank you!  I just can't find this anywhere in the documentation...  If you turn your comment into an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer in [one of koa's github issue](https://github.com/koajs/router/issues/76#issuecomment-1232034567). You need to simply create your router as follows:

```js
router.get('/foo/:splat*', async (ctx) => {
  // do what you want
});
```

Comment: Good catch! Apparently, I am not the only one caught by the lack of documentation of this feature ;-)